# Android studio warns about integer multiplication implicitly cast to long. How to fix this?

Tags: java, android, casting

```
 private static boolean isOverDate(long targetDate, int threshold) {
    return new Date().getTime() - targetDate >= threshold * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

I am using above function and Android Studio warns me about:

```
threshold * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000: integer multiplication implicitly cast to long
```

How to fix this? And why it warns?

Comment: what is your input in `threshold`?

Comment: Because your `targetDate` is `long`?

Comment: I am using this function at two places and passing 10 and 1 respectively as a threshold value to it.

Comment: Note that your code will be much easier to manage (and this method will be unnecessary) if you use the modern `java.time` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `max_int` is `2 147 483 648`.

If your `threshold` is more than 25 (25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 2.160.000.000), it will higher than `int` can hold. So you will need to cast to `long` or the result may be incorrect.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42671759/4316327

> If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the
> low-order bits of the mathematical product as represented in some
> sufficiently large two's-complement format. As a result, if overflow
> occurs, then the sign of the result may not be the same as the sign of
> the mathematical product of the two operand values.

Solution:

```
long timeToCheck = threshold * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;
return new Date().getTime() - targetDate >= timeToCheck;
```

or single line (different here is `L` after last number, it will understand that you will change type to `long`)

```
return new Date().getTime() - targetDate >= threshold * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;
```

or casting

```
return new Date().getTime() - targetDate >= (long) threshold * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Comment: How to fix this warning? Or just casting it to long will fix this?

Comment: @ChaitanyaKarmarkar you're welcome. I've just updated the answer 1 more time to let you and people come later can understand this.

Comment: You should consider casting the first operation to `long` rather than the last one.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so this is a bit complicated to unpick.

On the LHS (left hand side) of the `>=` expression we have:

```
new Date().getTime() - targetDate
```

The type of that expression is `long` because `targetDate` is declared as `long`.

On the RHS we have:

```
threshold * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

That is an `int` because all of the operands are `int`s.

However that expression is *likely* to overflow.  The value of `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is a "rather large", and when you multiply it by `threshold`, the resulting value is liable to be too big to represent as an `int`.  If it *does* overflow, then the result will be truncated, and the `>=` test will give the wrong result.

So ... the compiler is suggesting that you should do the RHS calculation using `long` arithmetic.  The simple way would be to declare `threshold` as a `long`.  But you could also cast it to a `long` as in:

```
((long) threshold) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

Comment: Nice answer. I included your answer in different question also.